# How to make a function checking how many consonants or vowels are in a string?

Tags: python, edx

I'm doing Georgia Tech's CS1301xII course, and I have been stumped by this question.
I am supposed to make a function called count_letters. If find_consonants is true, then it counts consonants, or vowels if it is false. It should only return vowels and consonants, no uppercase letters, spaces, numbers, or punctuation. The output I get is 0 consonants, then 1 vowel. I expected 14, then 7.

```
def count_letters(string, find_consonants):
    if find_consonants == True:
        count = 0
        for i in string:
            if i == ("q" or "w" or"r" or "t" or "y" or "p" or "s" or "d" or "f" or "g" or "h" or "j" or "k" or "l" or "z" or "x" or "c" or "v" or "b" or "n" or "m"):
                count += 1
        return count
    else:
        count = 0
        for i in string:
            if i == ("a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u"):
                count += 1
        return count
```

(The next section is just for me to test myself, the autograder changes the string)
a_string = "up with the white and gold"

```
print(count_letters(a_string, True))
print(count_letters(a_string, False))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test `if find_consonants == True` [is a bit overengineered](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/comparison_to_true.html). `if find_consonants` suffices. You might also want to make use of [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), to avoid the explicit loops.

This should work for instance:

```py
def count_letters(s, find_consonants):
    if find_consonants:
        return len([l for l in s if l in "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"])
    return len([l for l in s if l in "aeiou"])
```

Answer (score 3):

The `or` operation in python is lazy evaluation, like:

```py
>>> ('a' or 'c')
'a'
>>> ('c' or 'b' or 'a')
'c'
```

so `i == ("a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u")` equivalent to `i == 'a'`, is not the result you want.

You can change it like

#### Option1

This is crazy...though

```py
count = 0
for i in string:
    if (i == "a") or (i == "e") or (i == "i") or (i == "o") or (i == "u"):
        count += 1
```

#### Option2

This one is more elegant.

```py
count = 0
for i in string:
    if i in 'aeiou':
        count += 1
```

#### Option3

And this is Python

```py
len([x for x in string if x in 'aeiou'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you can't use `if var == "foo" or "bar"`; you'd have to write `if var == "foo" or var == "bar"`.
For your function, try something like:

```
def count(string, count_consonants):
    vowelcount = 0
    consonantcount = 0
    for letter in string:
        if letter in "aeiou": #Detect if letter is in vowel list
            vowelcount += 1
        elif letter in "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz":
            consonantcount += 1
    if count_consonants:
        return consonantcount
    else:
        return vowelcount
```

Comment: What doesnt work? The solution is correct. Well, with a minor caveat. The solution doesnt account for non alphabet characters, so may be better to add an elif with consonant character search

Comment: @vestronge Yes, that would be a best practice solution.

Comment: output is 1, 1 instead of 14, 7

Comment: I've put the full function in the post now.

Answer (score 0):

@ObseleteAwareProduce's solution is correct and addresses the concept of checking if an item matches any item in a specific list. But as far as finding vowels and consonants, we can use re library as well

```
import re

regex = re.compile("a|e|i|o|u", flags=re.I)
vowels_count = len(regex.finditer(input_string))
```

Comment: The autograder said it was wrong, and not one was right

Comment: libraries don't work for me, the course uses vocareum

Comment: Well we cant do everything for you. We didnt write the code as per the arguments and structure of your function to solve your test paper. That is for you to do. We pointed you in the right direction and guided towards correct understanding of "in" instesd of "or"

Comment: The first comment was about the other answer which you referred to.